# Get current time by city name

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the current date and time, by passing the city name, all I could find was to find it by time zone or latitude and langitude. Can anyone help me achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Too easy, All you need to do is:**

**1.** get lat,long by city name from google maps api

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=paris
```

**2.** get timezone by given lat,long in step one

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=43.29712312,5.382137115&timestamp=1374868635&sensor=false
```

**3.** get dateTime by given timeZoneId in step two

```
new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Europe/Paris"})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Ajax Request on the **World Clock** Search API. Than you get back the date e.g. on https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/germany/berlin

If you want it in native Javascript Code show us what you already have.

Comment: Thank you, but the free trial it's very limited to city I don't need. I'd like to do in a native code but I haven't done a function for it yet. I have a function where I get the city selected, so I could pass it as a variable