# Make returned date reflect city searched and not local browser date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I've created a React weather app that returns various pieces of info when you search by city. One of those pieces of info is the date. My problem is that the date returned reflects the date of the location where the browser is located. For example, if it is "12/20/2021" and I'm in Chicago but it's "12/21/2021" in Shanghai, when I search Shanghai from Chicago it shows the date as "12/20/2021" instead of the date in Shanghai. How can I get my app to reflect the date based upon the city being searched instead of based on where the user is located?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried, Stackoverflow will not let me post the code because I'm too new.

Answer (score 0):

[This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929214/get-current-time-by-city-name) may be of use; in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51929589) provides steps for how to translate your city first into its corresponding time zone, and then fetch the current time and date for that corresponding time zone.

Comment: This should be a comment. If you think the question is a duplicate, you should mark it as one.